# Find the indices of subarrays of single element

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of adjacency lists of a graph. I want to find the vertices whose degree is 1. For example, if `a=[[0,1,2],[1],[2],[1,2]]` then I want the indices `1`,`2` since `a[1]`,`a[2]` have single elements.

Comment: If you agree with this standard notion of [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) I guess you want to return vertices 0 and 3 since 1 and 2 have degree 3. Please explain what you mean with "have single elements"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for `sublists` with one element only, try this

```
[i for i in a if len(i) == 1]
```

Output:

> [[1](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [2]]

Its called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) where we create new list if sublists in original list contains only one element

**EDIT:** Since the above approach creates new lists of sublists, we need to flatten the lists

```
list(b for i in a if len(i) == 1 for b in i)
```

> [1, 2]

Comment: I am getting the output as [[1],[2]]. How can I just get [1,2] ? That is I don't want them to sub-arrays again.

Comment: @AshokVardhan check edit. also, this will extract the elements from the sublists not the indices. Please clarify what exactly you want the output to be? `elements` or `indices`

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `enumerate()` function:

```
a = [[0,1,2],[1],[2],[1,2]]
indices = [i for i, e in enumerate(a) if len(e) == 1] 
print(indices)
```